# Compile Linphone for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, armv7, libvpx

I'm facing an issue on compiling the NDK code. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04
x64. Basically i have performed the following steps:

1. Download the [NDK](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7b-linux-x86.tar.bz2). (I also tried the last one but the same issue)
2. Open terminal and make `sudo -s`. Input the root password.
3. `apt-get install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config`
4. Download source code through command:

   `git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive`
5. Go to my project root:

   `cd /home/silviu/linphone-android`
6. In my project root:

   `export PATH=/home/silviu/androidndk:$PATH`
7. Run `./prepare_sources.sh` in my project root.

I receive an error in `prepare_sources.sh`:

> Configuring selected codecs
>
> enabling vp8_encoder
>
> enabling vp8_decoder
>
> Configuring for target 'armv7-android-gcc'
>
> enabling armv7
>
> enabling armv6
>
> enabling armv5te
>
> enabling fast_unaligned
>
> enabling realtime_only
>
> Toolchain is unable to link executables
>
> Configuration failed. This could reflect a misconfiguration of your
>   toolchains, improper options selected, or another problem. If you
>   don't see any useful error messages above, the next step is to look at
>   the configure error log file (config.err) to determine what configure
>   was trying to do when it died. VP8 prepare stage failed.

Have anybody facing this issue?

Comment: I get the same error but on windows 7, and i am using cygwin with Devel plugins installed.